does the latest version of blender work on flame25 using rocky linux 9.3?
I went to blenders website and was not able to obtain these details through their FAQ, nor through their pdf manual, I had option to reach out to developers and report a bug but this isn't a bug issue. I'm just being tasked with identifying whether or not Blender software will work without issue on a Autodesk Flame 2025 on rocky Linux 9.3?

No idea what 'Flame 25' is. - It doesn't even appear if you stick it into Google. - Try it and see?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Apologies for this, i just edited my post to be more understandable, So i use Autodesk Flame 2025 on Rocky Linux 9.3 or at least ill be attempting this soon i decided to just check in here to see if anybody else has tried using the software with this specific linux OS. Autodesk Flame is a Video editing suite and 2025 is the latest version.
